# How to get the sum of combinations of variables of 2 columns in a tibble in r

Tags: r, tibble

```
     1       2     3       4              5
 1  2013     A     B      513            513         
 2  2013     B     A      533            524         
 3  2013     B     A      541            540         
 4  2013     B     A      544            532        
 5  2013     E     B      554            540       
 6  2014     F     B      557            558      
 7  2014     F     A      553            604
```

I have a tibble like that. How I can get the sum of every combination of the columns 2 and 3? So that I get 1 for A and B, 3 for B and A, 1 for E and B and so on.

Comment: pass column 2 and 3 as character, then make a new variable that is paste0(column1,column2), and then gen the length of the levels of the new variable

Comment: @SantiagoI.Hurtado that doesn't work and I am sure there's an easier way with `aggregate` or `summarise`and the `~` that I didn`t find yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group those two variables and summarise. Easy to do with `tidyverse`, although I'd change the names of the columns to text first.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
 group_by(col2, col3) %>%
 summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for, my R just hung up when I tried what the other commenter suggested lol

Comment: great - you may want to wrap the column numbers in back-ticks to avoid any further problems. Cheers.